# Storing latest input values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following HTML:

```
<input  class="type"  id="carbNumber">
<input  class="type"  id="otherId">
```

I want to store the input values in an object.

```
let data = {
    inputData: []
} 

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('blur', updateItem)

function updateItem(){
    data.inputData.push(this.value)
}
```

As I have multiple input elements I want to store their values in an array. If I input another value in the same input element - in which I had already input some other value - how can I figure out where I have stored the previous value the first time and therefore replace it with the new value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index number from the `input` elements as they are returned by `querySelectorAll`:

```js
const data = {
    inputData: []
}

// Use the callback argument of `Array.from` and the `i` index:
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'), (inp, i) => {
    inp.addEventListener('input', updateItem.bind(inp, i)); // pass `i`
});

function updateItem(i){ // capture `i`
    data.inputData[i] = this.value;
    console.log('inputData:' + data.inputData);
}
```

```html
<input id="a">
<input id="b">
<input id="c">
```

NB: I used the `input` event to display the results immediately as you type.

Comment: Nice, snippet, really. But this approach isn't reliable. The order could change for a variety of reasons especially since new (possibly hidden) inputs can be added to the page by frameworks, mashedup code or ads. Using an object is more reliable.

Comment: Why call this *unreliable*? The order will not change, since the order is taken at page load and then no longer looked at later. The binding of `i` is fixed and does not change.

Comment: Because he is going to do it multiple times. He said so specifically: _"but for example, I decide to input another value from the same input - from which I have already inputted some other value. How can I figure out what value, I have inputted the first time and therefore replace it with the new value?"_

Comment: Nevermind, I get it. He does say that, but your approach works assuming the event handler is the only thing that touches the object, since it binds `i` once. Still not as clear as straightforward as an object though. +1

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not use an array, use an object.

The object will map the ids of your input elements to their values

```
"use strict";
(function() {
  var values = {};

  function updateAllInputs() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function (input) {
      // ensures exactly one value per input (if all inputs have ids, adjust as needed)
      values[input.id] = input.value;
    });
  }

  // if you still need an array for some reason, you can create one from the object.
  function getSnapshotOfInputValuesAsArray() {
    return Object.keys(values).map(function(key) {
      return values[key];
    });
  }
}());
```